# PHP getrusage() returning incorrect information?

Tags: php, cpu, cpu-usage, ubuntu-8.04

I'm trying to determine CPU usage of my PHP scripts.  I just found [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/9-useful-php-functions-and-features-you-need-to-know/) which details how to find system and user CPU usage time (Section 4).

However, when I tried out the examples, I received completely different results.

The **first example**:

```
sleep(3);

$data = getrusage();
echo "User time: ".
    ($data['ru_utime.tv_sec'] +
    $data['ru_utime.tv_usec'] / 1000000);
echo "System time: ".
    ($data['ru_stime.tv_sec'] +
    $data['ru_stime.tv_usec'] / 1000000);
```

Results in:

```
User time: 29.53
System time: 2.71
```

**Example 2**:

```
for($i=0;$i<10000000;$i++) {

}

// Same echo statements
```

Results:

```
User time: 16.69
System time: 2.1
```

**Example 3**:

```
$start = microtime(true);  
while(microtime(true) - $start < 3) {  

}  

// Same echo statements
```

Results:

```
User time: 34.94
System time: 3.14
```

*Obviously, none of the information is correct* except maybe the system time in the third example.  So what am I doing wrong?  I'd really like to be able to use this information, but it needs to be reliable.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 8.04 LTS (32-bit) and this is the output of `php -v`:

```
PHP 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2010 22:01:14)
Copyright (c) 1997-2007 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2007 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: I'm also getting alot of weird behavior here. Probably due to the SAPI interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the system 'time' command to verify this information externally:

```
/usr/bin/time php script.php
```

which will print something like:

```
0.03user 0.00system 0:03.04elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 32752maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+2234minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Of course, dont't forget that the getrusage() information is CPU time used and microtime() is wall clock time. The program may run for 10 minutes according to the clock on the wall, but internally may only use a few seconds of CPU time. Then there's contending for CPU time with all the background programs running on the system, resource contention, plus regular housekeeping.

There's far too many factors involved to be able to get an accurate timing for such short periods. Doing three runs of the `while(microtime())` version of your loop, I got the following timings:

user: 0.98, 0.09, 0.90
sys: 0.12, 0.05, 0.94

Obviously quite the variance. Even just a simple `<? print_r(getrusage()) ?>` has utime/stimes ranging from 0 to 0.03.

Try running your loops for longer periods, and do something within them to increase cpu usage. Right now your numbers are too small to accurately measure.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that and let you know.  My issue is: all of the numbers are larger than should be possible.  Are you saying that because the numbers are so small, there are errors that cause the huge numbers?

Comment: I feel like I'm in the twilight zone.  I ran this test:

    for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {
            hash('sha512',uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
    }

And I got good results.  Then, I ran the exact same tests I posted in my question, and they all returned expected results - no more 35 seconds of user CPU time on a 3 second script.  I don't know what happened, but it's working now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, nevermind.  It's still giving me huge numbers randomly.  After doing a lot more testing it looks like really short times are just messing everything up.  I was already checking every script's run time, so my solution is to check if either user or system time is greater than runtime.  If it is, I ignore it.  If not, I use it.  I'll post my code in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Marc B's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732024/php5-getrusage-returning-incorrect-information/2732297#2732297), I was able to figure out that the ridiculously short times were causing errors in `getrusage()`'s calculations.

I have created a work-around to discard these inaccurate numbers.  Here's the code:

```
define('SCRIPT_START', microtime(1));

register_shutdown_function('record_activity');

/* Do work here */

function record_activity()
{
    $data = getrusage();
    $cpuu = ($data['ru_utime.tv_sec'] + $data['ru_utime.tv_usec'] / 1000000);
    $cpus = ($data['ru_stime.tv_sec'] + $data['ru_stime.tv_usec'] / 1000000);
    $renderedtime = round(microtime(1) - SCRIPT_START, 6);

    // Have some log function to put this info somewhere
    insert_record($renderedtime,
        //Only pass user CPU time if it's less than or equal to rendered time
        ($renderedtime >= $cpuu ? $cpuu : NULL ),
        //Only pass system CPU time if it's less than or equal to rendered time
        ($renderedtime >= $cpus ? $cpus : NULL ));
}
```

Hopefully, this will be helpful to anyone else experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Hrmm, this is a good idea but I don't know about the method. You are computing CPU time based on runtime, which is apples and oranges as others have mentioned. Recording `getrusage()` at the start of the script and using that instead would be more accurate.

There isn't really any way to get accurate CPU usage of an individual script running in most webservers. You will end up with the CPU time used by the parent Apache (or other) process, including runtime from unrelated scripts. Scripts run via CLI have their own execution environment and you should get much more accurate info with them.